# Catching SIGINT in kernel space

Tags: c, linux, kernel, signals, sigint

In my kernel module I have a function to start a firmware update via sysfs-attribute. This function blocks until the update returned successfully or after a timeout. The problem now is when I generate an interrupt by pressing Ctlr+c on the keyboard the function returns. This leaves the buffer with my payload for the update in an undefined state generating unwanted behaviour when restarting the update process.

I know from userspace that you can register a singal_handler to catch those specific signals like SIGINT in my case:

`signal(SIGINT,my_sig_int_handler)`

Is there something similar in the kernelspace? I also read that one should not use signal() at all because of compatibility issues but what would be the alternative?

I already tried to work with the function by registering my signal-handler function in my sysfs-function but it seems that the handler doesn't get executed:

```
static void sig_handler(int sig)
{
        printk("SIGINT received\n");
    // set global flag to inform other thread that uupdate was interrupted;
}


static ssize_t update_function(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *dev_attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
__sighandler_t  sa_handler = sig_handler;
kernel_sigaction(SIGINT,sa_handler);
// set flag to start update in other thread ....
}
```

In the linux-kernel sources I can't find examples where kernel_signal is used with a handler_function. Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve my problem?

Comment: Is blocking or otherwise handling the signal in user space not an option?  (You'd use like like `sigaction()` or `sigsetmask()` to do that robustly - not `signal()`.

Comment: No, you can't "register" a signal handler in the userspace sense. Internally, the kernel just marks the task block signal mask as pending. Only at the final step, just before reentering userspace, does the kernel look for a pending signal and adjust the userspace return to call a signal handler. There _are_ things you can do, but we need to see your kernel code to know what kernel functions you are calling. There are "uninterruptible" versions of some functions. Or, you can mask off the signals with internal equivalents to `sigprocmask`.

Comment: The functions you mention are only for kernel threads, not for syscalls your userspace program invokes. And, _In my kernel module I have a function to start a firmware update via sysfs-attribute._ What firmware and what device? And, why via sysfs vs. the userspace app opening `/dev/whatever` and doing an `ioctl`? Do you give the kernel the entire firmware as a single buffer or in chunks?

Comment: I'm working on a spi driver (as a kernelmodule) which has besides other things the functionality to do a firmware update of a second embedded device. The call of the sysfs-attribute (first thread) out of userspace is initiating a `request_firmware()`  and then setting a flag to inform another thread (second thread in the same kernelmodule) to start copieing the firmware chunk by chunk to the other device.